# Beamer: How to left-align equation with subitems

Tags: beamer

In the code given below, I want to change the following: I want the equations to be aligned with the subitems. Or at least move the equations further to the left - they are way to much to the right.

Is there a way of doing this? Maybe using subitems to give explanations to the equation is not a neat way?

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usetheme{metropolis}

\begin{document}

        \begin{frame}{State-Space Model}
        \vspace{-2.5cm}
        \begin{columns}[T]
            \begin{column}{.5\textwidth}
                \begin{block}{}
                    \begin{itemize}
                        \item State Equations:
                        \begin{equation}
                        x_k = A x_{k-1} + w_{k-1} \nonumber
                        \end{equation}
                        \begin{itemize}
                            \item k: discrete time index
                            \item x: state variable
                            \item A: state transfer matrix
                            \item w: process noise 
                        \end{itemize}
                    \end{itemize}
                \end{block}
            \end{column}
            \begin{column}{.5\textwidth}
                \begin{block}{}
                    \begin{itemize}
                        \item Output Equations: 
                        \begin{equation}
                        y_k = C x_k + v_k \nonumber
                        \end{equation}
                        \begin{itemize}
                        \item y: measurement
                        \item C: observation matrix
                        \item v: measurement noise
                        \end{itemize}
                    \end{itemize}
                \end{block}
            \end{column}
        \end{columns}
    \end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Maybe using `\PassOptionsToPackage{fleqn}{amsmath}` before `\documentclass{beamer}`gives your the desired result:   https://i.stack.imgur.com/9PaVx.png

Comment: i wouldn't use bullets in variables list. just variables.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the `fleqn` environment from `nccmath`, you can align your equations either with the item or the subitem very easily:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{amsmath, nccmath}
\usetheme{metropolis}

\begin{document}

        \begin{frame}{State-Space Model}
        \vspace{-2.5cm}
        \begin{columns}[T]
            \begin{column}{.5\textwidth}
                \begin{block}{}
                    \begin{itemize}
                        \item State Equations:
                        \begin{fleqn}
                        \begin{equation}
                        x_k = A x_{k-1} + w_{k-1} \nonumber
                        \end{equation}
                        \end{fleqn}
                        \begin{itemize}
                            \item k: discrete time index
                            \item x: state variable
                            \item A: state transfer matrix
                            \item w: process noise
                        \end{itemize}
                    \end{itemize}
                \end{block}
            \end{column}
            \begin{column}{.5\textwidth}
                \begin{block}{}
                    \begin{itemize}
                        \item Output Equations:
                        \begin{fleqn}[\dimexpr\leftmarginii]
                        \begin{equation}
                        y_k = C x_k + v_k \nonumber
                        \end{equation}
                        \end{fleqn}
                        \begin{itemize}
                        \item y: measurement
                        \item C: observation matrix
                        \item v: measurement noise
                        \end{itemize}
                    \end{itemize}
                \end{block}
            \end{column}
        \end{columns}
    \end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

with `flalign` from the `amsmath` package and without bullets in variables lists:

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usetheme{metropolis}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{State-Space Model}
\begin{columns}[T]
\begin{column}{.5\textwidth}
        \begin{itemize}
            \item State Equations:
            \begin{flalign*}
            x_k & = A x_{k-1} + w_{k-1}   &
            \end{flalign*}
        where are:
            \begin{itemize}
                \item[$k$:] discrete time index
                \item[$x$:] state variable
                \item[$A$:] state transfer matrix
                \item[$w$:] process noise
            \end{itemize}
        \end{itemize}
\end{column}
\begin{column}{.5\textwidth}
        \begin{itemize}
            \item Output Equations:
            \begin{flalign*}
            y_k & = C x_k + v_k           &
            \end{flalign*}
            \begin{itemize}
            \item[$y$:] measurement
            \item[$C$:] observation matrix
            \item[$v$:] measurement noise
            \end{itemize}
        \end{itemize}
    \end{column}
\end{columns}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: thx a lot to you as well!